# shorten url in a column in text file

Tags: awk

I have text file similar to this:

```
http://domain/section1/section2/resource.html http://domain/section1/section2/resource1.html
http://domain/section1/section2/section3/resource2_4.html?param=param1 http://domain/section4/section5/resource3.html
```

There are 2 columns with urls. Number of sections in each url might be different. I need to remove the trailing part of each url in first column. E.g.

```
http://domain/section1/section2/ http://domain/section1/section2/resource1.html
http://domain/section7/section2/section3/ http://domain/section4/section5/resource3.html
```

My current approach with awk seems to be fragile and doesn't cover all use cases:

```
awk -F'[\t ]' '{sub(/\/[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+$/,"\/",$1)}1'
```

because resource name may contain non ascii symbols (e.g. german's umlauts) and it doesn't work for resources which have query parameters.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```sh
awk '{sub(/[^\/]+$/,"",$1)}1'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Dnb7Z1).

*Details*:

- `-F'[\t ]'` can be removed because by default `awk` splits the records into fields using spaces/tabs chars
- `sub(/[^\/]+$/,"",$1)` will remove all one or more chars other than `/` that are followed with end of string in Field 1
- `1` at the end will trigger the default print command.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. This will handle edge case of spaces in between urls to be taken care here. This will also look for http or https both kind of urls, in case you need only http to be matched then change from `^http[s]?` to `http` in following code.

```
awk -F'\\.html(\\?[^ ]*)? +http' '
{
  match($1,/^http:\/\/.*\//)
  $1=substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  $2="http" $2
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F'\\.html(\\?[^ ]*)? +http' '  ##Setting field separator as .html OR .html? till space comes followed by http here.
{
  match($1,/^http:\/\/.*\//)        ##Matching from starting of http till / in $1.
  $1=substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)      ##Saving matched regex part into 1st field.
  $2="http" $2                      ##Adding http in starting of 2nd field.
}
1                                   ##Printing current line.
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's:[^/]* : :' file
http://domain/section1/section2/ http://domain/section1/section2/resource1.html
http://domain/section1/section2/section3/ http://domain/section4/section5/resource3.html
```

.....